# One parameter solutions to the differential equation $y'(x) = -\frac{x}{1+y}\,e^{-x^2}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, absolute-value

I've already worked out the solutions to it, 2 explicit functions of x:

y1 = $-1 + \sqrt{c1+1-e^{-x^2}}$

y2 = $-1 + -\sqrt{c1+1-e^{-x^2}}$

What I want to know is,
Can you express the general solution as a *genuine* one-parameter family of solutions (i.e., with the use of $\pm$) by using the sign-function `sgn` and the absolute value function?

Answer (score 0):

$$2y^\prime(1+y)=-2xe^{-x^2}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}(y^2 +2y) = \frac{d}{dx} e^{-x^2}$$

$$y^2 + 2y = e^{-x^2} +  \text{const.}$$

$$(y+1)^2 = e^{-x^2}+ \text{const.}$$

$$y=\mp\sqrt{e^{-x^2}+c}-1 $$

Comment: Yes, but what about the sgn and absolute value function?

Comment: Do you mean *without* the use of plus/minus?

Comment: Also, my answer and your answer seem to differ in the sign in front of the exponential.

Comment: Ok I'll correct it. Aso yes without.

Comment: This seems to me to be the most general form.  If you had an initial value problem (where you specified $x(0)$, for example), then you would only have one of these curves and $c$ would be determined.

Comment: huh...I kinda came to the same conclusion but figured I was wrong. I've stuck trying to make a solution with sgn and abs functions

Comment: Thank you for posting the question.  I guess that's about all we can say about it.